# Trying to understand where a variable is getting it's value from in this mini-program

Tags: c

I am working on a mini-project for school. This mini-program works and gives me the expected outputs but this is not enough for me. I'm a strong believer in really understanding *why* a program/code does what it does.

I have tried breaking the code down into pseudocode but I still can't get my head around where the variable `triangularNumber` is getting it's value from.

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("This program will calculate the triangular number of n\n");

  double n, sum, triangularNumber;
  triangularNumber = 0;

  printf("Enter (n): ");
  scanf("%lf", &n);

  for (sum = 1; sum <= n; sum += 1)
    triangularNumber += sum;

  printf("The triangular number of %.2lf = %.2lf", n, triangularNumber);

  return 0;
}
```

So my question is, where is `triangularNumber` getting its value from? I defined it with the value of 0 and I can't see where and how it is getting another value when printed in the final `printf` statement.

`triangularNumber += sum;` to me is the same as `triangularNumber = triangularNumber + sum` but in my eyes, looking at it from the perspective of the values, this is just like saying `0 = 0 + sum`. If `n` had the value of `10`, wouldn't `sum` also have the value of `10`?

Just as a courtesy, an input of 10 will output 55.

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain this for me so I can get a better understanding of loops for my school. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here: `triangularNumber += sum;`.

Comment: `a += b` means the same as `a = a + b`.

Comment: @Blaze I get that that's where it is coming from but I want to understand *how* and *why* it is getting the value

Comment: Note that you can get the answer simply by computing `n*(n-1)/2`. I know it is not the question, it just for you to know

Comment: Aside: triangular numbers are integers, so `double` isn't very appropriate here.

Comment: @Sam So at each pass to the loop you will take the current value of triangularNumber and add to it the current value of sum. Since sum loops between 1,2,...,n this is similar to writing 1+2+..+n

Comment: If you add some `{` braces `}` and add another `printf` statement inside the loop so you can see the values of `triangularNumber ` and `sum` progressing, the workings might be a bit clearer.

Comment: I think that you will get a lot of good explanations just by googling for loops explanation or maybe even check some youtube videos. For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NZZ9Y-j_mw. Any case, for each loop you have to define where it starts, where it end and the size of step to do. In this case you start with `sum=1` and each iteration you increase it by 1, the number of iterations in this case is `n`. So you will get eventually 1+2+3+..+n as people said.

Comment: Its value is `1+2+3+4+....n`

Comment: This is where you need to study how a debugger works. Launch the source in a debugger, make sure to watch all variables involved. Single step through the program and watch them change. This is the most effective way to learn how _any_ program behaves, far more effective than asking random internet people a question about every single program you come up with.

Comment: As a side-note, using floating point numbers as loop iterators is a bad idea, due to their inaccuracy.

Comment: Upvoted because you wanted to understand it even though it is already working (as opposed the all too common do my homework for me questions).

Answer (score 4):

Modify the `for` loop like this:

```
  for (sum = 1; sum <= n; sum += 1)
  {
    triangularNumber += sum;
    printf("triangularNumber = %d\n", triangularNumber);
  }
```

Then run the program again, look at the output and you'll understand.

Comment: Okay just by simply adding curly braces this has helped hugely. I think I was struggling to visualize where it was getting it's value. Now I see it is being looped within the for loop code block it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you understand

```
double /*...*/ triangularNumber;
triangularNumber = 0;
```

and

```
printf("The triangular number of %.2lf = %.2lf", n, triangularNumber);
```

The only other line with `triangularNumber` is this:

```
triangularNumber += sum;
```

This is the short way of saying

```
triangularNumber = triangularNumber + sum;
```

which means "add the value of `sum` to the value of `triangularNumber` and store the result in `triangularNumber`."

Or shortly "add `sum` to `triangularNumber`."

There might be some reasons for such an operator like `+=`:

1. It saves typing.
2. It prevents accidental errors through typos.
3. It shows more clearly what you mean.
4. In the old days of primitive compilers it was a hint for a compiler to use simpler assembly code.

You can combine all (please correct me if I'm wrong here!) binary operators this way, for example `*=`, `|=`, `<<=`.